# Windows 8 equivalent for windows phone marketplacesearchtask

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, winapp

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent of the `MarketplaceSearchTask` of window phone for `Windows 8`? 
I'm going to launch a series of applications onto the windows 8 marketplace and I would like to users could push it somewhere else. Then you would be able link it to the marketplace i.e. to your own account so they could see all your applications.

I've searched for a long time, but I haven't found anything. Does someone here know an answer to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think something identical would be possible with the current Windows 8 APIs, so your best bet is to display links to apps that are either hardcoded into your app (that you could update with an app update) or host a service that does the search and displays the results inside of your own app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below Uri to launch your apps:

```
ms-windows-store:Publisher?name=[your publisher display name]
```

Any spaces in your publisher name should be rendered as %20.