# Windows 8 and WP8: URL to send the user to the list of my developer apps on the store?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Anybody knows what is the URL to send the user to the list of my developer apps on:

- Windows 8 store ?
- WP8 store ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 8 apps, you can use below Uri to launch your apps:

```
ms-windows-store:Publisher?name=[your publisher display name]
```

Any spaces in your publisher name should be rendered as %20.

Answer (score 0):

On WP8:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394001(v=VS.92).aspx

Use your publisher name as search term.

```
MarketplaceSearchTask marketplaceSearchTask = new MarketplaceSearchTask();

marketplaceSearchTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Apps;
marketplaceSearchTask.SearchTerms = "*publisher name*";

marketplaceSearchTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows 8 store there does not appear to be an equivalent to MarketplaceSearchTask. Check out this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186465/windows-8-equivalent-for-windows-phone-marketplacesearchtask) for more info.